# Javascript function not firing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a Javascript function in which on click of a button, a post request will be sent to another file. If this request is successful, the button will be disabled and its color changes. An alert will be returned as well.

```
$(document).on("click", ".employeeComplete", employeeReg);

    function employeeReg(self, name){
        self = $(self);
        var stats   = {};
        stats['age']  = 'age';
        stats['name'] = name;
        $.post('employee', stats)
        .done(function(e){
            alert("hello");
            if(e){
                alert("This employee has been registered.");
                self.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                self.css('background-color', '#111111');

            }
            else{
                alert("Error.");
            }
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert("Error.");
        });

        self.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
```

in the first line, i had previously had parantheses after my function name as such:

```
$(document).on("click", ".employeeComplete", employeeReg());
```

but that fired the function on page load, not on button click. Upon removing the parentheses, the function doesn't work on button click or page load at all. Thanks.

**edit**

my sselector was misspelled, but the only the alert is being returned, no button change or disable.

when i change `self` to `this` or `$(this)` (Also removed the `self` variable and parameter from function) , i receive the following console error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: Are you sure your class selector matches the element you're clicking on?

Comment: firstly check that your selector is valid (i.e. the element being clicked on has the class "employeeComplete"). We can't see your HTML so can't verify it for you. Secondly check your console for errors. Thirdly set a breakpoint in the JS to check it really isn't being fired at all.

Comment: Look at the console, you probably have an error caused by `self = $(self);` the first argument to a jQuery event listener callback, is the event object.

Comment: Can you share your HTML , sounds like  `.employeeComplete` dont exist

Comment: ok so my selector was wrong, now its returning the alert on button click, but the button doesnt disable or change color. @JamesThorpe

Comment: @ADyson no console errors

Comment: You should probably [edit] that information into your post, or at least correct it to the behaviour you're now seeing.  Though @Titus has probably hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @Titus i think that might be why the button isn't disabling or changing color. its returning the alert but not doing the button stuff. im not getting anything on the console though

Comment: not sure that `self` is a valid argument to the callback - check Titus' comment. As usual in Javascript you can use `this` to represent the item  which was the source of the event (i.e. the button). The first (and generally only) argument sent to the callback by the system will be the event data. You don't get to choose what the callback parameters are because you're not triggering the callback!

Comment: @JamesThorpe i updated my question

Comment: @ADyson using `this` was returning console  errors for me, i updated my answer

Comment: @jrdev I would guess you didn't use it correctly. See the answer i just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (and generally only) argument to an event callback is the event data itself. This is done by the browser JS engine and is not something you can influence or choose yourself.

To get the item clicked on, within the callback context, you can always reference `this`.

See example below (in order to make a runnable demo I've commented out the ajax part, the purpose is to demonstrate the correct use of `this`).

```js
$(document).on("click", ".employeeComplete", employeeReg);

function employeeReg(event) {
  var self = $(this);
  var stats = {};
  stats['age'] = 'age';
  stats['name'] = name;
  /*        $.post('employee', stats)
          .done(function(e){
              alert("hello");
              if(e){
                  alert("This employee has been registered.");
                  self.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  self.css('background-color', '#111111');

              }
              else{
                  alert("Error.");
              }
          })
          .fail(function(){
              alert("Error.");
          });*/

  alert("This employee has been registered.");
  self.css('background-color', '#111111');
  self.attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="employeeComplete">Click to test</button>
```

N.B. Also consider switching ".attr" for ".prop" - see documentation at http://api.jquery.com/attr/ which states: "As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method." . There is also a more detailed discussion of why this is the case.

Comment: @jrdev No problem - please remember to mark the answer as "accepted" if it helped, thanks :-)